# Magento 2 issue on header minicart

Tags: magento, knockout.js, magento2

Im having problem on integrating header mini cart into my custom theme. Below are the screenshots of the issue. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Screenshots:
[image]

[image]

Below is the default.xml code.

```
    <referenceContainer name="header.container">
        <container name="header-wrapper" label="Page Header" as="header-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="top-header">

            <!-- top links with cart -->
            <container name="topcartoptions" label="Top Cart Options" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="top-cart-options text-right" before="-">
                <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block-top-links">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block-top-links</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>

            <!-- top menu --> 

            <container name="mainnavigation" label="Main Navigation" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="main-navigation" after="topcartoptions">
                <container name="main-navigation-container" label="Main Navigation" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container">
                    <container name="main-navigation-container-row" label="Main Navigation" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="row">
                        <container name="main-nav-row-bootstrap-class" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
                            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block-main-nav">
                                <arguments>
                                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block-main-nav</argument>
                                </arguments>
                            </block>
                        </container>
                    </container>
                </container>
            </container>


            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar" name="minicart" as="minicart" after="logo" template="cart/minicart.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="types" xsi:type="array"/>
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart</item>
                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/content</item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="subtotal.container" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">subtotalContainer</item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/subtotal</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="extra_info" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">extraInfo</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="promotion" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">promotion</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
                <container name="minicart.addons" label="Mini-cart promotion block"/>
            </block>


        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Can you please show some code or link to a fiddle? That would be helpful..

Comment: I updated my post and I added the piece of code of layout.xml where I put the minicart layout.

Comment: can you also provide the html mark up that is generated?...and if possible some piece of viewmodel

Comment: This is the view source screenshot: http://content.screencast.com/users/noprobz09/folders/Jing/media/ddb046ee-022d-4e3a-a146-b2c14d0634aa/2016-10-27_1622.png and when I tried to inspect the element this is the the screenshot, http://content.screencast.com/users/noprobz09/folders/Jing/media/bbd5e73d-3cbc-4e19-8323-5aae08bd0375/2016-10-27_1629.png.

Comment: My custom theme parent is Magento/blank, Im a bit curious why the mini cart recent added items not showing, by the Im a magento 2 newbie here :(

Comment: After looking at the images provided, I would suggest you to put a break point inside the `getRegion` and `getItemRenderer` methods and see if the object your are trying to bind to has a property named `simple`....best of luck..